# Android Studio code coverage for unit test shows 0% for some (empty) classes

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage

Consider the following class:

```
package com.zao.sample;

import com.zao.sample.ITruck;
import com.zao.sample.Car;

/**
 * Created by Zach on 5/19/2017.
 * Truck base class.
 */
public class Truck extends Car implements ITruck {
}
```

With `ITruck` being an empty interface (for now, until I flesh that out) and `Car` providing basic functionality to a car type class.

My simple test class for this is an empty test class basically:

```
package com.zao.sample;

import com.zao.sample.Truck;

/**
 * Created by Zach on 5/19/2017.
 * Tests the {@link Truck} class.
 */
public class TruckTest{
}
```

When I run `JUnit` tests with coverage, this particular file is reported with the following statistics:

```
Class %: 0% (0/1)
Method %: 0% (0/0)
Line %: 0% (0/1)
```

Is there any way to make the coverage report 100% for this class?

Edit: If I were to add a sample test like this:

```
@Test public void sampleTest() {
    Truck truck = new Truck();

    Assert.assertNotNull(truck);
}
```

Line % changes to 100%, so that's progress, but Class % remains at 0%.  Method % being at 0% makes sense - there are no methods to test, thus it will always be 0%.

So is there any way to make the Class % goto 100% in this case?

Comment: How many tests are being runned? 0. So a 0% of classes, methods and lines are covered. Seems pretty logic to me

Comment: @Pelocho If I add a 'dummy' test that creates a Truck object and does something simple like `Assert.assertNotNull(truck)` it still reports the same values.  In this case there are now tests being run, which create objects of the class being tested/reported on, but the reported values are still 0%.  I will update my question to include this example.